# What is OnFocusChange Listener in Android?

Tags: android, listener, onfocus

I am now learning Android and one exercise is requiring me to implement `onFocusChangeListener` when a `EditText` is touched. However, I was able to find very little information about `onFocusChangeListener`. On the Android Development website [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) there is very very brief information. I have done search but I was only able to find some posts about the specific problems developers have encountered where very few information was given. Can anyone give me an introduction here or any link that talks about that more in detail?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the link you posted says,

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the focus state of a view changed.

and if you read what the `params` mean

> Parameters
>
> v         The view whose state has changed.
>
> hasFocus  The new focus state of v.

So if you set this on a `EditText`, or multiple `EditText`s, you can use the `v` param to know which `View`s focus has changed. And you can use `hasFocus` to determine if it did just gain focus (`returns true`) or if it has just lost focus because it was given to someone else (`returns false`).

So, maybe you want to start some `animation` on a `View` when focus is changed on it or another `View`, you set this listener and when it is invoked you can start the `animation` if `hasFocus` returns `true`.

If you are still confused then please explain *what* you don't understand about it.

As for the docs not giving much information, they assume that when reading this you have adequate information of what `listeners` and methods do and about how to use `parameters` that it takes and returns. The docs also expect a certain knowledge of Java. So for your other question, I know if I don't understand something because I don't think the Android docs have covered it thoroughly, then I would check the Java docs.

[Java Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/)

[Java 6 Docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F6%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F&ei=gblEUvqgH4G8rQHd2IH4CA&usg=AFQjCNFpxRlGAcehtEfz5-_uNP9ISpSpIg&sig2=YslarPMdxLau3pVP1CrIiA&bvm=bv.53217764,d.aWM)

Comment: thank for that detailed explanation. Now I have quite good understanding about it, just a last question, is the implementation of this listener same as onClickListener?

Comment: Yes, you set it basically in the same way if that's what you mean.