# Determine onAlert shown and dismissed in Android

Tags: android

I have to determine when alert is shown and dismissed in android. I don't have access to alert box object on the screen. One of the way to solve this problem is listen for onWindowFocusChanged event using ViewTreeObserver on root view.  OnWindowFocusChanged is not supported below API level 18

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener.html

Any other way to solve this for API level below 18 ?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039850/what-is-onfocuschange-listener-in-android